# How can I implement a progress bar on front-end showing the information about an API call progress?

Tags: angular, api, flask, progress-bar

I'd like to realise a progress bar on my front-end that can show the progress on a certain api call. This API call can take some seconds to complente and send the response back to the front-end, so I though it'd be nice to give the user information about the execution.

My problem is I don't know how to send information about the progress from the back-end to the fronted.
I though about a web socket channel but I don't know that is the correct/best way to do that.

I'm using Angular as fronted Framework and Flask to build the Python API.

Comment: by using mat progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Angular Progress Bar Design You have Angular Material
https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview

Since you're using Angular, you're probably calling the server with HttpClient, right?
The HttpClient module returns an Observable from the RxJS library, which sends the information from the server to subscribers.
Normally you will have no information about the progress of the call to the server. You will only receive the information as it arrived in its entirety.
That's why you have 2 options: or fake a progress of a counter from 1 to 100 in an average period of time using setTimeout
Or use the Indeterminate progress bar